# Transformation matrix to go from one vector to another

Tags: matrices, transformation, 3d

I've two vectors $a = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3)$. How to find  transformation matrix for transform from a to b?

Comment: You need some restrictions. For example if a=(0,0,0) and b is anything else, there's no possible transformation matrix.

Comment: @coffeemath sure, you can check my answer, in that case one will not be able to find axis of rotation (and angle of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use axis-angle representation to get the rotation matrix.

$$Rot(u,\phi)=I \cos\phi + u u^T(1-\cos\phi) + \hat{u}\sin\phi$$
where $u$ is unit axis vector and $\phi$ is angle of rotation.

To find axis vector you need to use cross product of given two vectors $(\overline a\times\overline b)$, and from this cross product you can get first $\sin\phi$ and then $\cos\phi$.

- [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)
- [Hat operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_operator)

Comment: It's better to use the dot product to calculate the angle  instead of cross product since doing so via cross product maybe ambiguous due to the fact that sin(x)=sin(π-x).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [dyadic product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Dyadic.2C_outer.2C_and_tensor_products), the definition is
$$
    \mathbf{a b} \equiv \mathbf{a}\otimes\mathbf{b} \equiv \mathbf{a b}^\mathrm{T} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1b_1 & a_1b_2 & a_1b_3 \\ a_2b_1 & a_2b_2 & a_2b_3 \\ a_3b_1 & a_3b_2 & a_3b_3 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$

You can construct the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ you're looking for as following
$$
\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{R} \mathbf{a} \\ \\
\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{3}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{a_1}b_1 & \frac{1}{a_2}b_1 & \frac{1}{a_3}b_1 \\ 
\frac{1}{a_1}b_2 & \frac{1}{a_2}b_2 & \frac{1}{a_3}b_2 \\ 
\frac{1}{a_1}b_3 & \frac{1}{a_2}b_3 & \frac{1}{a_3}b_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix}
\\
\mathbf{R} = 
\frac{1}{3}
\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{a_1} & \frac{1}{a_2} & \frac{1}{a_3} \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: and interchange a and b...

Comment: A rotation matrix must satisfy $R R^T = I$, this clearly doesn't hold up for your suggestion

Comment: What if one component of $a$ is zero? The inversion will fail.

Comment: @kvphxga it's just a mapping, not a rotation...

Comment: @EverettYou you're right. I should exclude this...

Comment: but how to define this matrix if the vectors have zero elements? there is division by zero

Comment: The weakness with this is that it assumes that every element of the matrix is of equal importance in transforming the components of a into the components of b, when some parts of a may carry more weight than others in the system being modeled. But if you only know one pair of vectors, that's 6 measurements for 9 unknowns, you don't know enough to correct the weightings, and this is a great place to start if there aren't any zeros. It shows the logic of the matrix, and starts to make the process of refining it with multiple understandable.