# Finding matrix to transform one vector to another vector

Tags: matrices

If I have an arbitrary vector $A = (a,b,c,0)$ how can I find a transformation matrix $M$ such that $M \times A = (0,1,0,0)$?

We can assume $A$ has a magnitude of $1$ if it helps simplify the derivation process.

The trivial case $A = (0,1,0,0)$ would cause $M$ to be the identity matrix.

If $A = (0,-1,0,0)$ then $M$ would be a 180 degree rotation matrix about the $x$ axis.

I heard of Rodrigues' rotation formula from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209768/transformation-matrix-to-go-from-one-vector-to-another) but I'm not sure how it would work in a 4 by 4 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since $B=(0,1,0,0)^T$ is very simple and $A=(a,b,c,0)^T$ is not we can consider
   $$M_1=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&a&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&c&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$ which satisfies $ M_1B=A$ which    is not satisfactory since we are looking for all $M$ such that $MB=A$. Furthermore $M_1^{-1}$ does not exist. So we rather perturbate $M_1$ in
   $$M_2=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&a&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&c&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right].$$ Assume that $b\neq 0;$ then $\det M_2=b,$ which implies that $M_2$ is invertible. Since $M_2 B=A$  then $M_3=M_2^{-1}$ is a solution since $M_3 A=B.$ Finally all others $M=M_3+M_4$ such that $MA=B$ are such that  $M_4 A=0$. If $R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4$ are the rows of $M_4$ then $M_4A=0$ if and only if for $i=1,2,3,4 $ we have $R_iA=0.$ Plenty of solutions...

Finally if $b=0$ imitate the method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning Rodrigues' rotation formula, you may be interested in this alternative method:

Represent A and B as quaternions: $$Q_A=a*1+b*i+c*j\\ Q_B=1*i.$$Now compute the transformation quaternion $Q_R$ =$Q_B/Q_A$ by using Hamilton's product, getting $Q_R*Q_A=Q_B$. Next you take (one of the) real 4*4 matrix representations $M$ corresponding to the quaternion $Q_R$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations)), and by translating the quaternion equation back to a matrix equation, you immediately get $M*A=B$ as requested.